# How to create select dynamic fields from a table in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I have query join in select statement like this :

```
select a.item_number, total_quantity, store, factory
from (
    select item_number, sum(quantity) as "total_quantity"
    from `item_details`
    group by item_number
) `a` 
left join (
    select item_number, sum(quantity) as 'store' 
    from `item_details` where location_code = 'STORE' 
    group by item_number
) `b` on `a`.`item_number` = `b`.`item_number` 
left join (
    select item_number, sum(quantity) as 'factory' 
    from `item_details` 
    where location_code = 'FACTORY' 
    group by item_number
) `c` on `a`.`item_number` = `c`.`item_number` 
order by `item_number` asc
```

From the query above, it appears if I use table `item_details` with fields id, item_no, quantity and location_code

If the query executed, the result like this :

[image]

The results are correct. But here I want to create field store and factory to be dynamic. So it's taken from table locations. Because the data location is dynamic. It can be added and removed

So I have table locations with field id and description like this :

[image]

field location_code in the item_details table is foreign key to field id in locations table

So how to create select dynamic fields from location table?

Note :

I use "query join in select statement" because I didn't have table locations before. Now I use table locations. Because the data in the location table is dynamic. It can be added and removed. So I want to display it like table 1 above with table location. Seems it need to join the table. But i'm still confused to do it

Comment: @Barmar Why is this question marked as duplicate? It really doesn't help me

Comment: You asked about creating dynamic columns in MySQL. That's what a dynamic pivot is.

Comment: @Barma Yes. But seems my case is a little different from that case

Comment: I've reopened. You need to explain your problem more clearly. Show the result you're trying to get. And make an attempt to code it yourself, then we'll help you fix it; we don't write the code for you from scratch.

Comment: @Barmar Okay. But seems I had explain my problem more clearly. But I will try to update it again

Comment: See all the linked questions on the right. They all show how to write dynamic SQL to do this. Try to implement it, and post your attempted code.

Comment: @Barmar Okay.  I am trying harder to understand the process. This case is really difficult

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not tested ,create a fiddle if you find errors.

```
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'ifnull(SUM(case when location_code = ''',
      location_code ,
      ''' then quantity end),0) AS `',
      location_code , '`'
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM
  item_details;
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT item_number,SUM(quantity) as "total_quantity", ', @sql, ' 
                  FROM item_details
                   GROUP BY item_number');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;

DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: Thanks. But I'm really confused with the script. Can you explain in more detail? Or provide solutions to other answers that are easier. Now I am trying harder to understand the process

Comment: I did not find `select * from locations` in the your script. How to take the field?

Comment: I had try your script, there is no error. Column total_quantity, the results are correct. But column store and colomn factory, the result is incorrect

Comment: @SuccessMan It`s hard for me to guess where the problem might  be.Create a sqlfiddle and try to reproduce the problem with a few rows of data. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: Okay. I will create a sqlfiddle

Comment: Look at this : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c8f62b/4. There exist error

Comment: Seems it works. But I will review it again. I want to ask. Are there other solutions without many statements? Because there exist `PREPARE`, `EXECUTE` etc

Comment: So I mean, is it possible to only use 1 statement for this case?

Comment: There are solutions but you have to hardcode ALL the values,smth like SUM(CASE WHEN location_code = 'FACTORY' blah) and so on for each value.The dynamic pivot has the advantage you dont need to specify those values even if you add or delete new locations.

Comment: Okay. I using laravel framework. I must convert mysql query to laravel eloquent. It's a bit difficult. Because there are many statements

Comment: put this line `SELECT @sql;` before PREPARE... it will output the resulted query.You can copy that.

Comment: Where line `SELECT @sql`? I don't find it

Comment: I received your answer because actually your answer had answered my question. For conversion problems to laravel eloquent. That is another problem. Thanks

Comment: I want to ask again. Can you help me?

Comment: So I want to add conditions before sum quantity. I have another field called `type`. if(type = "sales") then sum quantity. Like that. How can I add it?

Comment: `SELECT item_number,SUM(CASE WHEN type='sales' THEN wahatever END)as smth,SUM(quantity)`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using stored procedure then your query will become easy to use dynamically.
Dynamic column name you can manage by integer number or name of columns.
store your existing query in the variable and use If condition to concat your dynamic query 
 in variable. at last execute the statement by defined variable.

you can take reference from below link for execute the dynamic code.
[mysql dynamic query in stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23178816/mysql-dynamic-query-in-stored-procedure)